# How to get the OpenAPI specification for kubernetes objects

Tags: json, kubernetes

For example,  for the kubernetes pod , it is something like this ( copied from a book , but the author did not mention from where can I get this , he says , the openAPI sepcification) :

```
{
 "name": "pods",
 "singularName": "",
 "namespaced": true,
 "kind": "Pod",
 "verbs": [
 "create",
 "delete",
 "deletecollection",
 "get",
 "list",
 "patch",
 "proxy",
 "update",
 "watch"
 ],
 "shortNames": [
 "po"
 ],
 "categories": [
 "all"
 ]
```

How and from where can I get this for other kubernetes objects like RS , SVC , Deployments etc

Comment: You failed to include in your question any URIs that you have already consulted, which for sure should include the URLs that are printed when the apiserver Pod starts up

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel your query is irrelevant ,  it has nothing to do with API server start up , I am just asking the kubernetes resource object definitions

Comment: @GhostCat question updated...

Comment: it's not irrelevant, you asked where the openAPI specification lives, and I'm telling you that apiserver emits those URLs on startup [as one can see here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1243827) with the text `[restful] 2015/07/16 08:19:18 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://192.168.100.206:6443/swaggerapi/` <-- any guesses what content lives at that URL?